# RStudioで Markdown の出力時、警告が出て止まってしまう

Tags: r, markdown, rstudio

RStidioでパッケージをロードすると、マークダウンの出力画面では警告が出て(しかもその警告の文が途中までで)、以後の処理は行われず止まってしまいます。

左上画面でチャンクごとに実行したところ、以下の警告が表示されますが、以後の処理もチャンクごとに実行することはできています。

```
Warning: package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 4.1.3
Warning: package ‘readr’ was built under R version 4.1.3
```

csvファイルの読み込みが正常にできているので、readrパッケージのロード自体はできているようです。

Answer (score 0):

> R本体を4.2.1をインストールしなおして、
> それからまたKnitしようとしたらmarkdownパッケージがないというダイアログボックスが出て、それに従ってmarkdownパッケージをインストールしたら、正常に動作するようになりました。